# Не отображается изображение

Tags: php

```
<?php

$img = imageCreateTrueColor(400, 350);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img, NULl, 100);

?>
```

Если закомментировать header, то выведется символы изображения

Если убрать комментарии, появляется вот это:[image: вот это]

Данный код списал с видео урока, у автора появился небольшой черный прямоугольник на белом фоне, у меня же все на оборот.

И когда появляется этот черный background, title изменяется на содержимое адресной строки.

Версия php 7

Comment: Включена ли у вас библиотека GD?

Comment: В файле php.ini у меня убрана точка с запятой перед gd2

Comment: $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Невозможно инициализировать GD поток');

Comment: И к чему этот `NULl, 100`

Answer (score 0):

`$bg = imagecolorallocate ($img, 255, 255, 255);`

`imagejpeg($bg, NULL, 100);`

`header("Content-Type: image/jpeg")` Говорит браузеру что это картинка jpeg, а не html страница.